# Importing CSV and updating records if exists in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

Model:

```
def self.import(csv_file)
    line = 2
    errors = []

    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
      order = Order.find_or_initialize_by(projectid: row["projectid"], batch: row["batch"])
      order.assign_attributes(row.to_hash)
      if order.valid?
        order.save!
      else
        errors << line
      end

      line += 1
    end

    return errors
  end
```

here is the updated model code based on suggestions below; BIG thanks to Daiku and madcow thus far.

I think the reason that the record is not updating has to do with order.assign_attributes(row.to_hash) based on testing another and I did using the code above in the console, but with hard values.

I am trying to see what that code is doing now.

Comment: Are you saying that if a record already exists with the same `projectid` and `batch`, that you want to update the existing instead of creating a new record?  Is it creating new records when it shouldn't?  What's the actual error message or unexpected behavior?

Comment: Yes Daiku; if there is a projectid and batch the record should update otherwise it should load a new record.

I am getting Order Exists in the console, but no update to the record with changed data.  It is not creating new records when it shouldn't, it just isn't updating existing records with any data that may have changed.

Comment: Put in a breakpoint right after `assign_attributes`.  Then in execute `order.valid?` and see what the status is.

Comment: `{"id"=>nil, "projectid"=>"TSTTST1ABCP01", "batch"=>"1", "ppiho"=>"2015-11-02", "needby"=>"2015-10-02", "quantity"=>"192", "manufacturer"=>"J&J", "model"=>"Test", "CAR"=>nil, "cfnum"=>nil, "prnum"=>nil, "ponum"=>nil, "status"=>"Quote Completed", "contact"=>"Name Test", "notes"=>nil}`

that is what row.to_hash is providing to order.assign_attributes for the test record.

I am changing the ppiho that is in the system.  Current in the system is 2015-12-01 and I am trying to get it to update to 2015-11-01 as a test case.  It is not updating it. I get Order Exists (8.9ms) in the console.

Comment: When you say you are getting "order exists in the console", do you mean it is refusing to save?  Do you have an index set up on those two columns with a uniqueness constraint?  Also noticing that `id` is nil.   That strikes me as odd.  Move the breakpoint up one line and see if you actually got a record?  Is `assign_attributes` blowing away the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was multifaceted and Madcow, Daiku, and Jake to an extent all had a piece of it.

The updated code in the original post now works fantastically.  I had put an id column in the csv file that I was uploading thinking it needed to be there to work.  It did not need to be there, in fact it needed to not be there.

{"id"=>nil, "projectid"=>"IADTST1RWKP01", "batch"=>"1", "ppiho"=>"2015-11-02", "needby"=>"2015-10-02", "quantity"=>"192", "manufacturer"=>"Delta", "model"=>"US Cords", "CAR"=>nil, "cfnum"=>nil, "prnum"=>nil, "ponum"=>nil, "status"=>"Quote Completed", "contact"=>"Mike Salafia", "notes"=>nil}

when that hash was presented to the order it rejected it because id was trying to be set to nil and it cannot be nil.  However, I don't need id in the csv file to find the order and update it or create a new order as the projectid and batch can be used for find and the id is auto assigned.

So I needed a return, Daiku made me look at the hash harder, and Jake's code would also likely work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Update will attempt to save the item before updating it so it works with new records as well as found records.

```
def self.import(csv_file)
  CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
    order = Order.find_or_initialize_by(projectid: row["projectid"], batch: row["batch"])
    if order.update(row.to_hash)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1. Not sure exactly the context but if the use case includes updating the `batch` for an existing `project_id`, `find_or_initialize_by` is not finding the existing item because it is looking for a record that has **both** the same `project_id` and `batch`.
2. Is `projectid` a typo? Should it be `project_id`?

Updated:

Also, you should have a `return` inside of the foreach loop or it will abort early.

Comment: I am using the returns in the controller to trigger messages on the upload page.

I have only been doing RoR for about 4 months and when I made the table column names I didn't do it properly and it is too far along for me to go back and change them so sadly it is projectid instead of the accepted prohect_id.

The funny thing is that it shows it is finding the record in the console.  I get Order Exists in the console, but it's not updating.  I am using a specific test projectid with the same batch # to try and verify function.

Comment: In ruby the last line of a method returns the expression value. In other words, having the last line as 'order.save' is the same as saying 'return order.save' which will return false or true.

Comment: I tried it with just 

`if order.valid? 
  order.save`

and it doesn't return true or false to the controller so no messages were happening.  It did import the new record though.

It is still not updating records either.

Comment: that's because in your code, if the order is not valid it is not calling `order.save` (so the method would return nil). Again, `order.save` already runs the `valid?` validation check so that `if order.valid?` is not needed.

Comment: ah, I see; so I need nothing more than order.save.

just tried that and there was no messages.

Controller code:
`def import
    if params[:csv_file].present?
      result = Order.import(params[:csv_file].tempfile)
      if result == true
        flash[:notice] = "upload successful"
      elsif result == false
        flash[:error] = "error uploading"
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Please choose a file"
    end

    redirect_to '/orders/upload_page'
  end`

Comment: Wait I just noticed that the return is in a foreach block. Could this be your problem with it not updating records? Is it returning early (before it has iterated through all the rows)???

Comment: Hard to say since I am only using 1 row of records to test and even with that the row isn't actually being updated in the database.

You can see in my comment above to Daiku that the row.to_hash is passing in the new data, but the system is kicking back an order exists and not updating the field that has changed.

Comment: Oh my how could I miss the return; I changed some things.  Error reporting is better, but still not updating.  I will update the original post with the new code